# Drupal 7 Views that receive nid from url

Tags: filter, drupal-7, view

I want to create Drupal 7 views that receive nid from url then return all nodes that are above this nid.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal Views explore 'Contextual Filter' you will get an idea.

Ref url
[http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views](http://buildamodule.com/video/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7-advanced-views-how-contextual-filters-work-in-the-views-module)
http://buildamodule.com/video/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7-advanced-views-how-contextual-filters-work-in-the-views-module

Cheers!!!